# Awslog rotate: keep initial log file permissions

Tags: amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch

When using awslog service to rotate log files, I have found that initial file permissions are not respected for the newly created files after rotation.

Steps:

1. File is created with 660 rights:

   ```
   $ ll /var/log/*.log

   -rw-rw---- 1 root root 0 Jan 11 07:07 /var/log/app/my_log.log
   ```
2. Service awslog is restarted with proper stream configured:

   ```
   $ cat /var/awslogs/etc/config/awslogs-larbiz-api.conf

   [/var/log/app/my_log.log]
   file = /var/log/app/my_log.log
   log_group_name = app/my_log.log
   log_stream_name = {instance_id}
   ```
3. Restart service to take config into account:

   ```
   $ sudo service awslogs restart
   ```
4. File keeps initial permissions

   ```
   $ ll /var/log/*.log    

   -rw-rw---- 1 root root 1940223 Jan 11 07:07 /var/log/app/my_log.log
   ```
5. Then rotation takes place, and I got this (note the missing write permission for the group)

   ```
   $ ll /var/log/*.log

   -rw-r----- 1 root root 1940223 Jan 11 07:07 /var/log/app/my_log.log
   -rw-rw---- 1 root root 1940223 Jan 11 07:07 /var/log/app/my_log.log.1
   ```

Which is a problem to me.

In the [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html) I have failed to find any attribute to set file permissions / ownership

So...

**How do I keep the initial file permissions using awslogs?**

Comment: I can confirm that I see the same result as you, the agent only gives write access to the owner of the log file when it rotates and there is no configuration options to change the file acl.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Hope someone have an answer for this :)